# AS3 - removing childs in parent container doesn't reposition childs correctly

Tags: actionscript-3, grid, click, containers

I made this plugin wich positions all child objects of a container in a grid formation. Now I added a clickhandler to the childs in the container, and when I click one of them, it is removed. When I remove a full row (from top to bottom) on the right hand side, all goes well, but when I remove a full row on the left hand side, the position of all the items in the container stay on their place but the container itself will be moved to x = 0 and y = 0. What I want is that all childs in the container are moved to x:0, y:0 as one group.

some pictures on what I get and what I want:

**1) What I get:**

[image: What I have on startup]

**2) What I get when I remove a full row on the left:**

[image: What I get when I remove a full row on the left]

**3) What I want:**

[image: What I want]

**The code I use:**

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {


    var name:String = event.currentTarget.name;

    if(container.getChildByName(name) != null)
    container.removeChild(container.getChildByName(name));
    trace(name, "container.width: ", container.width);
    trace(name, "container.width: ", container.height);
    trace(name, "container.x: ", container.x);

    container.graphics.clear();
    container.graphics.beginFill(0x2C2C2C);
    container.graphics.drawRect(container.x ,container.y, container.width, container.height);
    container.graphics.endFill();

}
```

Anyone got an idea on how to fix this? :)

**EDIT: Code for creating the grid:**

```
private function generateGrid(rows:int, cols:int, spacing:int):void
    {
        for (var py:int = 0; py <rows; py++)
        {
            for (var px:int = 0; px <cols; px++)
            {
                if(childs.length > 0)
                {
                    var child:* = childs.shift();

                    child.x = (child.width + spacing) * px;
                    child.y = (child.height + spacing) * py;

                } else {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of creation that grid? I still can't understand, why you think that childs should be re-aligned.

Comment: Ok ) Please, give us more information: what type of containers do you use? It is not MovieClip or Sprite, is it? And what type of array elements at `childs.shift();`?

Comment: the container is a sprite and the Draw object are extended from Sprites. the childs.shift(); are the Draw objects (the squares), there I position the squares in a grid formation. The only thing the plugin does is repositioning the items in a grid formation

Comment: Do the children hold any data about which column/row they are stored in?

Comment: no not yet, I could implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Grid extends Sprite{

        private var _squ:Square;
        private var _cont:Sprite;

        public function Grid() {
            // constructor code
            _cont = new Sprite();
            addChild(_cont);
            for( var i:uint = 0;i< 20; i++){
                _squ = new Square(50,50,2,Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
                _cont.addChild(_squ);
                _squ.name = "square_"+i;
                _squ.x = 100 + 52 * Math.round(i%5);
                _squ.y = 50 + 52 * Math.floor(i/5);
                _squ.buttonMode = true;
            }           
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickAction);
        }
        public function gridAlign(cont:Sprite):void{
            for( var i:uint = 0;i< cont.numChildren; i++){                              
                _cont.getChildAt(i).x = 100 + 52 * Math.round(i%5);
                _cont.getChildAt(i).y = 50 + 52 * Math.floor(i/5);
            }
        }
        private function onClickAction(e:MouseEvent):void{
            _cont.removeChild(_cont.getChildByName(e.target.name));
            this.gridAlign(_cont);
        }
    }   
}
```

try this.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really anything to 'fix', you just haven't written any code to move those objects, so they're not moving. You're redrawing the background of the container based on the new width, but you haven't actually moved any of the objects inside that container.

There are a lot of ways you could do this. The simplest solution that comes to mind would be something like this:
- loop through all the children of the container and **find the lowest x position**.
- loop through again and **subtract that lowest x value from the x position of each child**.

(You probably want to do this for the y position too, so they'll move up when you remove the top row.)

You would run that entire process each time a child is removed. If the lowest position is 0, meaning there is an object in the leftmost position, then nothing moves, if there is a blank row, the lowest x will be greater than 0, and everything will move over by that amount.

**Disclaimer:**
It would probably be 'better' to not muddle the graphical views with the data structure so much, but that's the best suggestion I can offer without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: the code is rather complicated, and to post it all would be a mess, I might post the full code ;)

Comment: That's ok, I just meant you can probably find a more flexible and efficient way to do it, depending on how your code is structured. What I wrote above should work fine, or at least get you started in the right direction.